# How can I get round value from a object in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I had an object that has a table value and I wanted to sum the column named first and total_unload. When I was trying to sum it was not getting the exact value that I want, means I wanted to get rounded value of the sum. I have tried this line of code.

```
{{ ($unload->sum("first") * 100) / $unload->sum("total_unload")  }} %
```

Please can anyone help to get the rounded value from my tried code.

Comment: Using the function `round()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{ round(($unload->sum("first") * 100) / $unload->sum("total_unload")) }} %
```